# Extract data from YAML file

Tags: perl, yaml

I need to pick up values associated with the variables from a YAML file using Perl.

I have tried this so far.

```
my $fh = new FileHandle; 
my $mydir = "/proj/1a/ct_tst/cf";
my $file  = "tsan.yml";
opendir($dh, $mydir) or die ("Cannot read directory!\n");
open($fh, "< ${mydir}/${file}") or die ("Cannot read file $file!\n");
```

It works to load a file. But, I am not sure how to proceed to get the values corresponding to variables in the YAML file.

Comment: `YAML::XS` would help you to parse the yaml file.

Comment: @vkk05: Perhaps adding a link to [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS) would be helpful to the beginner :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a YAML parser (like [YAML.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod)).

```
use YAML;

my $data = LoadFile("$mydir/$myfile");
```

Now, in `$data`, you will have a Perl data structure containing all of the data from the YAML file. But as I don't know what your YAML looks like, I can't help you extract specific data from it.

Comment: `LoadFile(*STDIN)` loads from standard input.